# Palabras al azar

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber como hago para que en mi base de datos se guarden palabras al azar:

Por ejemplo ya hice el intento guardando letras del 1 al 7 con el siguiente método:

```
    rand(1,7);
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo se puede escribir esta función pero guardando 7 palabras u oraciones diferentes al azar?

Por ejemplo: perro, gato, hola que haces, bien y tu, programar, otra palabra, azar

Aqui ya hay 7 palabras de ejemplo: ¿Como hace que me salga una de esas al azar?

Comment: -¿Que motor de base de datos manejas?

Comment: Pues creo que el dilema es más bien como generar palabras aleatorias con Java. Ahora bien, la rutina también podría generarse en la propia base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es seleccionar una de esas frases al azar, puedes hacerlo asi:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] x = {"perro", "gato", "hola que haces", "bien y tu", "programar", "otra palabra", "azar"};
        Random rand = new Random();

        int n = rand.nextInt(7);
        String z = x [n];

        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```